# Как в jquery искусственно вызвать событие назначенное какому-либо элементу?

Tags: jquery

Допустим какому-то элементу назначено событие:

```
$('#someelement').click(function() {
    // обработчик события 1
});
```

и нужно вызвать обработчик этого события, например, по другому событию:

```
$('#otherelement').keydown(function() {
    // обработчик события 2
    // а вот здесь надо вызвать обработчик события 1.
});
```

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#otherelement').keydown(function() {
   $('#someelement').click(); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#someelement').trigger('click');
```

Источник:
http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F